# Representing 2d space of indeterminate size with JS arrays - negative indexes?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to represent 2d cartesian cordinates in a 2d JS array.  The 2d space is of indeterminate size (can extend into -x and -y space too).  This is fine for positive x and y values, but with a minimum index of 0 in JS arrays I can't extend into negative x and y space.

I have read some short information about the possibility of using negative indexes in JS, and that apparently these are technically possible, though not properly supported (e.g. array functions moght not work properly).

I'm sure others must have had a similar requirement, so I'd like to ask - what's the recommended way of modelling this in JS? Are negative array indexes a workable solution?

Comment: hmm, first thing that comes into mind is an object, containing 2 arrays, one for the positive end and another for negative end. not sure how to handle 2 zeroes though, or making them continuous.

Comment: @Joseph, yeah I was thinking along those lines too, but I feel like it might get messy when dealing with things that overlap the +/- boundaries.  There's also the zero issue you mention...

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need negative indizes? Usually every coordinate system for computer graphics starts at (0/0) in the upper left screen corner. And they draw their axes somewhere else.

So, the solution for a finite size is just transforming the coordinates. Also, you *can* use negative indizes on Arrays, but better call that "keys on array Objects". If you know their limitations, you can use them:

- Array.length works only for positive indizes.
- Therefore, you can't loop from 0 to a.length - you will have to find another solution. (and don't think of for-in).
- So, you will need to determine a negative start for the loop - let it be a constant, or even another property of your array Object (without the auto-update feature!).

But, you say your space is indeterminate. The problem is just that there is no inifinite data structure - in no programming language. Of course array indizes could get very big, but do you really need them? I'm very sure that a twodimensional array with a size of (2^32)^2 is nothing but a huge waste of memory space - or at least something that makes your application extremely slow.

It might be better to think of a one-dimensional array with objects representing points in. You can easily loop over it, you can have any number for coordinate values and they don't need that much memory.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the space is not a 'pre-known' finite size (it's not a screen) - so I can't transform :(   You've made some good points - I'll give them some thought. thanks.

Comment: It does not need to be pre-known, it just needs to be finite all the time. The boundaries and the transformation function may change during runtime.

Comment: ah yes, got you.  Well it does not have to be 'infinite', just big enough to seem that way.  So some kind of dynamic transform function might be an option.  However, wouldn't you need to 'shift' the whole array every time you increased the -ve boundaries? Presumably by copying to new array - sounds expensive!

Comment: Just another thought: You know a projection from ℕ → ℤ? ([example](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abzählbarkeit#Ganze_Zahlen)) :-) the loop will be awful...

Comment: No, in JS you don't need to copy the array. You can both unshift() and push() - it's a list in effect. Also, if you have a intelligent transformation function you can make use of the negative indizes - just store the lower limit somewhere.

Comment: Right - was still thinking that I couldn't use the array support functions,  thanks.  Will have to get back to you on the projection thing!