# Should negative indexes in JavaScript arrays contribute to array length?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In javascript I define an array like this

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
```

also I can do

```
arr[-1] = 4;
```

Now if I do

```
arr = undefined;
```

I also lose the reference to the value at **arr[-1]**.

SO for me logically it seems like arr[-1] is also a part of **arr**.

But when I do following (without setting arr to undefined)

```
arr.length;
```

It returns **3** not **4**;

So my point is **if the arrays can be used with negative indexes,** these negative indexes should also be a part of their length**.
I don't know may be I am wrong or I may be missing some concept about arrays.

Comment: Why would you want to use a negative index? That's very confusing. I don't see the point unless I'm missing something.

Comment: You can also write `arr[1.5] = 1` and that also does not affect the length. The language specification is very clear about what affects the length. You may not like it but you have to live with it. Either that or design your own competing language and convince people to switch to it.

Comment: @elclanrs: This is not about just using negative indexes. If this facility is given by the language, then definitely there should be a proper reason for it.Otherwise this looks like a flaw.

Comment: @DigvijayYadav: Could be considered a flaw or a feature like many other things in JavaScript. This is because arrays behave a bit like objects, you can also use a string `var a = []; a['foo'] = 'baz'` but that doesn't mean you should; it's clearly against all conventions.

Comment: Guys, the main point here is that ARRAYS ARE OBJECTS. There is no difference. That is the reason for this behavior, and it's completely intentional even if you don't like it. Just wait until you learn that ALL numbers are represented as floating point, even integers. JavaScript is a curious language...

Comment: You can find details of the algorithm that defines the setting of array elements in the specification: http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.5.1.(especially step 4) and "array index" is defined here: http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.

Comment: @Felix dear god, those links are rabbit holes =)

Comment: @Tony: I know :D But if you really want to understand something, read the spec ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why array in JavaScript showing wrong length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333000/why-array-in-javascript-showing-wrong-length)

Comment: @FelixKling - I think given _that_ spec it might be more appropriate to say "If you really want to understand JavaScript have somebody else explain the spec to you"...

Comment: I guess you wanted to do this because you wanted n analogy with python

Comment: @elclanrs it can be useful for default state. you have an array that defines steps but each step depend on the previous one. the code for 0th index would require a lot of `if`s or just a -1th index with default values that works with the code written for normal step

Answer (score 124, accepted):

> SO for me logically it seems like arr[-1] is also a part of arr.

Yes it is, but not in the way you think it is.

You can assign arbitrary properties to an array (just like any other Object in JavaScript), which is what you're doing when you "index" the array at `-1` and assign a value. Since this is not a member of the array and just an arbitrary property, you should not expect `length` to consider that property.

In other words, the following code does the same thing:

```
​var arr = [1, 2, 3];

​arr.cookies = 4;

alert(arr.length) // 3;
```

Comment: Ok, It means negative indexes don't actually act like real indexes.

Comment: Right, they're just arbitrary properties on the array.

Comment: But what if I want to use positive indexes as properties not like indexes and I don't want them to contribute to the array length?

Comment: Then don't use an array, use a plain ol' object. But in that case you'll lose the built in `length` property.

Comment: Also when I define arr[-1] = 4, if I console the arr I get only the initial array. Not the whole object with -1 as a property.
If I want to access the [-1] property I have to use arr[-1]. So if I have to do this, I don't see arrays as real objects.

Comment: @Yadav See my answer. Then see Ashan's answer for how to print an object.

Comment: @Digvijay: The console only shows the properties with positive integer  names because (I assume) it just does an ordinary `for` loop from `0` to `.length`. Do `console.dir(arr)` to see the complete object. Also, using bracket notation to access arrays is not a characteristic of arrays, it's an inherent characteristic of objects (`var obj = {foo: 'bar'}; obj.foo or obj['foo']`).

Comment: @DigvijayYadav: That's just the console representation which doesn't show you non-numeric properties on Array objects. It's still there.

Comment: there's a great article on this up on medium which is worth a read; https://medium.freecodecamp.org/learn-these-javascript-fundamentals-and-become-a-better-developer-2a031a0dc9cf

Comment: Is there a way to prevent code from adding arbitrary properties or negative indexes? Can "use strict" prevent this ?

Answer (score 28):

The `length` property will return a number one higher than the highest assigned "index", where Array "indexes" are integers greater than or equal to zero. Note that JS allows "sparse" arrays:

```
var someArray = [];
someArray[10] = "whatever";
console.log(someArray.length); // "11"
```

Of course if there are no elements then `length` is `0`. Note also that the `length` doesn't get updated if you use `delete` to remove the highest element.

But arrays are objects, so you can assign properties with other arbitrary property names including negative numbers or fractions:

```
someArray[-1] = "A property";
someArray[3.1415] = "Vaguely Pi";
someArray["test"] = "Whatever";
```

Note that behind the scenes JS converts the property names to strings even when you supply a number like `-1`. (The positive integer indexes also become strings, for that matter.)

Array methods, like `.pop()`, `.slice()`, etc., only work on the zero-or-higher integer "indexes", not on other properties, so `length` is consistent on that point.

Comment: Thank you your answer helped a lot. Also I tried the splice method with negative index, I found that if I use -1 it goes to the last element of the array, for -2 goes to the second last element and so on.

Comment: +1. Length doesn't tell you how many elements there are, or how many properties there are. It's just the highest index + 1. e.g. given `var a = new Array(9)`, `a` has a length of 9 and no elements at all.

Comment: @DigvijayYadav - Yes, the [`Array.slice()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) is supposed to do that. The [`String.slice()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) does the same thing.

Answer (score 11):

Note that when you use a position (or 0) index, values are placed within the array:

```
var array = [];

array[0] = "Foo";
array[1] = "Bar";

// Result: ["Foo", "Bar"]
// Length: 2
```

This is not the case when you add non-index values (not 0-9+):

```
var array = [];

array[0]  = "Foo";
array[1]  = "Bar";
array[-1] = "Fizzbuzz"; // Not a proper array index - kill it

// Result: ["Foo", "Bar"]
// Length: 2
```

Values are only placed in the array when you play by the rules. When you don't, they aren't accepted. They are however accepted on the Array object itself, which is the case with just about anything in JavaScript. Even though `["Foo", "Bar"]` are the only values in our array, we can still access `"Fizzbuzz"`:

```
array[-1]; // "Fizzbuzz"
```

But note again that this isn't part of the array values, since its "index" isn't valid. It was instead added onto the array as just another member. We could access other array members in the same fashion:

```
array["pop"]; // function pop() { [native code] }
```

Note here that we're accessing the `pop` method on the array, which informs us that this contains native code. We're not accessing any of the array values with a key of "pop", but rather a member on the array object itself. We can further confirm this by cycling over the public members of the object:

```
for (var prop in array) 
    console.log(prop, array[prop]);
```

Which spits out the following:

```
 0 Foo
 1 Bar
-1 Fizzbuzz
```

So again, it's *on* the *object*, but it's not *in* the *array*.

Awesome question! Caused me to do a double-take for sure.

Comment: +1 Even the specification states that properties with a positive numerical property name are called *elements* of the array (and any other property is not): http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.

Comment: Result is not: `["Foo", "Bar"]` but `["Foo", "Bar", -1: "Fizzbuzz"]` check [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/pg8wrdLs/). Like you wrote it becomes a property with key -1 but it is definitely visible in the output. Otherwise your answer is nice and complete. If you change I will upvote again, my downvote was to harsh, but can't remove it; time expired.

Answer (score 6):

If you really want negative indexes and other indexes to be included in the length, then create the functionality yourself:

```
function getExtendedArray() {
    var a = [];

    Object.defineProperty(a, 'totalLength', { 
        get : function() { return Object.keys(a).length; }
    });

    return a;
}
```

Then for example:

```
var myArray = getExtendedArray();
console.log(myArray.totalLength); // 0
myArray.push("asdf");
myArray[-2] = "some string";
myArray[1.7777] = "other string";
console.log(myArray.totalLength); // 3
```

Comment: And if you want the length to include only the **numbered** indexes/properties you can add an if statement for the key - `if(Number(key) != NaN) length++;`
If you want to filter out the float ones add `&& key % 1 == 0` to the condition

Answer (score 4):

Arrays in JavaScript are actually objects. They are simply prototyped from the Array constructor.

Array indices are actually keys in a hashmap, and all keys are converted to strings. You can create any key (i.e. "-1"), but the methods on Array are tailored to act like an array. So `length` isn't the size of the object, it's rather only guaranteed to be larger than the largest integer index. Similarly, printing `arr` will only list values with integer keys >= 0.

[More info here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Array)

Comment: exactly. or we could start wondering why array['foo'] isn't a valid index -- javascript allows you to do it, but doesnt mean that the definition of what an array (and its elements) change from one language to another. working as intended.

Comment: In fact "arrays" don't exist in JS. But "associative arrays," also known as "objects," are at the core of JS. So it wasn't a huge leap to make an Array object that imitates a regular array.

Comment: There is one very special difference between arrays and plain objects: the self-adjusting length property.

Answer (score 4):

*Array* is just a special kind of *Object* in JS. There is a special syntax, which is good, because it allows us to work with them effectively. Imagine how tedious would it be to write an array literal that way:

```
const array = {0: 'foo', 1: 'bar', 2: 'baz'} //etc...
```

But *they are still objects* nevertheless. So if you do:

```
const myArray = [42, 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

myArray[-1] = 'I am not here';
myArray['whatever'] = 'Hello World';
```

Those non-integer properties will be attached to an object (which array is), but there are not accessible by some native methods like `Array.length`.

<del>You can assume that the native 'length' method is a getter which counts all properties (and indexes *are* properties, while values are the actual *values*) convertible to positive integer or zero. Something like this pseudo-implementation:</del>

Due to [specs](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-array-exotic-objects), the native `length` method – as a *getter* (`exampleArray.length`) – will check all  'nonnegative integer less than 2<sup>32</sup>' keys, get the greatest one and return its numeric value + 1.

As a *setter* (`exampleArray.length = 42`), it will either create some empty slots for 'missing' indices if the given length is greater than the actual number of nonnegative integer keys, or delete all nonnegative integer keys (and their values) which are not greater then the given length.

The pseudo-implementation:

```js
const myArray = {
  '-1': 'I am not here', // I have to use apostrophes to avoid syntax error
  0: 42,
  1: 'foo',
  2: 'bar',
  3: 'baz',
  whatever: 'Hello World',

  get myLength() {
    let highestIndex = -1;
    for (let key in this) {
      let toInt = parseInt(key, 10);
      if (!Number.isNaN(toInt) && toInt > -1) {
        // If you're not an integer, that's not your business! Back off!
        if (toInt > highestIndex) highestIndex = toInt;
      }
    }
    return highestIndex + 1;
  },
  set myLength(newLength) {
    /* This setter would either:
      1) create some empty slots for 'missing' indices if the given length is greater than the actual number of non-negative-integer keys
      2) delete all non-negative-integer keys (and their values) which are not greater then the given length.
    */
  }
}

console.log(myArray.myLength); // 4

myArray[9] = 'foobar';

console.log(myArray.myLength); // 10
```

Answer (score 1):

According to MDN:

> The value of the length property is an integer with a positive sign and a value less than 2 to the 32 power (232)

In Javascript you can set a property on any object you create.

```
var array = new Array();
array = [1,2,3];
array["boom"] = "pow";
```

In the same way when you set a negative index it stores it as a property on the array rather than part of the index.

```
array[-1] = "property does not add to array length";
```

This is why the length doesn't reflect it but a for..in loop shows it.

Answer (score -1):

When you use non-positive or non numeric indexes the array behaves as an associative array which has key-value pairs.

To iterate through the array you can use

```
for(var index in myArray) {
  document.write( index + " : " + myArray[index] + "<br />");
}
```