# How to select the last thing in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
var myarray = [];

var result1 = myarray[0];
var result2 = myarray[1];
var result3 ....etc...
```

Selecting first is easy, cause it's just 0. How do I put the last one into a var? It seems like such a simple question but I must have been googling wrong cause I could not find any answer that worked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var last = myarray[myarray.length - 1];
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

Comment: @KevinB Yeah, even better

Comment: How about checking if the array is empty first?

Comment: @RobinSalih The question was "How to select the last thing". An empty array does not have a "last thing". In fact, the implementation should always check this.

Comment: If the array is empty, you'll correctly get undefined. I don't see a problem with that.

Comment: @still_learning: fair point, however I don't like example code on the internet that ignore these things, they get blindly copy and pasted into production code.

Answer (score 3):

myarray.length returns the length of array and as the elements have started from 0 subtracting one from it will give the index of last element

```
var lastresult = myarray[myarray.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var l= myarray[myarray.length - 1];
```

Check this **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)**.

Answer (score 1):

```
var lastelement = myarray[myarray.length - 1]
```

Comment: Also, this is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216013/get-the-last-item-in-an-array

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to do something like this

```
var lastElement = myArray[myarray.length-1]
```

Don't overthink. Arrays may be 0 indexed in javascript but that just means that the last index has to be the length of the array -1.

Answer (score 1):

Just this:

```
var lastResult = myarray[myarray.length - 1];
```

You can create prototype to do this more simple. For example:

```
if (!Array.prototype.last){
  Array.prototype.last = function(){
    return this[this.length - 1];
  };
};
```

and than use

```
myarray.last();
```

Comment: Extending native prototypes is bad practice according to mdn: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Bad_practice.3A_Extension_of_native_prototypes You don't have to when you do: `last = lastInArray.call(arr,arr);` still have you method use `this`

Answer (score 1):

you could use array prototype method `.pop()` **but that will remove last item from array**:

```
var lastElement = myarray.pop();
```

Or wrap array in jq object:

```
var lastElement = $(myarray).get(-1);
```

Comment: Given the question didn't indicate anything about changing the contents of `myarray`, this answer really isn't correct.

Comment: Getting ("selecting") should not cause side effects.

Comment: @admdrew sorry, my bad, misread question

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong about this, so perhaps someone else can tell me if I'm right or wrong, but can't you just do:

```
var last = myArray[-1]
```

?

EDIT: I'm wrong. Ignore me.

Also, out of curiosity, would it be faster to use

```
var lastelement = myarray[myarray.length - 1];
```

or

```
var lastelement = myarray.reverse[0];
```

?

Comment: `so perhaps someone else can tell me if I'm right or wrong` What happens when you try this yourself? :)

Comment: This will return `undefined` as `-1` is not a valid index of a JavaScript array.

Comment: Hmm, just tested it. I get 'undefined'. I really thought that was possible.

Comment: negative index works only in jquery: `$(array).get(-1);`

Comment: Yeah. I did a little more digging on this. Turns out that negative indices can be used to assign properties to an array object, but they do not affect length. This thread does a good job of explaining it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618571/should-negative-indexes-in-javascript-arrays-contribute-to-array-length.