# JavaScript negative element in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my JavaScript array code for negative index number.
In output why doesn't consider negative index number in the count of the element? It shows only count (3) in output.

**Code**

```js
let abc = ['gnagar', 'ahmedabad', 25];
console.log(abc, typeof(abc));
console.log(abc[-1]);
abc[-1] = 'abc';
console.log(abc, typeof(abc));
console.log(abc[-1]);
```

Comment: Because `array` starts from 0

Comment: These indexes are non-negative integers and Starts from 0
check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618571/should-negative-indexes-in-javascript-arrays-contribute-to-array-length

Comment: Seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what is the problem that you're trying to solve with a negative index in an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `array` is type of object as you can see there `typeof(abc)` is object.

You can assign values in objects using `[]`.

Negative indexes are not actual index so it does not impact the array length.

Answer (score 1):

`-1` is not a valid index for array.

The assignment `abc[-1] = 'abc';` means set attribute "-1" to the abc object.