# Values of variables with negative and big array indexes does not save in local storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage, negative-number

I have variable with uncommon array indexes. Here it is:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUde8.png

So, I save it into local storage:

```
function Save(){
    var save = {
        //<...>
        MapCellData: MapCellData,
        MapCellDataE: MapCellDataE
        //<...>
    };
    localStorage.setItem("save",JSON.stringify(save));
}

window.setInterval(function(){
   Save()
}, 10000); // Autosave every 10 sec
```

Then I go to Firebug console and check what elements were saved by entering the following command:

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("save"));
```

This is what I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Om15A.png

As you see, all values of variable with negative indexes and big indexes became undefined while indexes from 0 to 4 were saved properly.

Note: MapCellData is variable which determines which image will be applied to the table cell, and MapCellDataE is variable which determines cell background colour. Both of these variables have same indexes, so both share the same problem. Variables that does not have so strange indexes saves properly.

This is how it looks visually.

Before I reload a page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2V7E.png

After I reload a page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWicG.png

Comment: What are "uncommon array indices"? Your code doesn't show any arrays.

Comment: Yes, `JSON.stringify` does only serialise array indices on `Array` objects, and discards all other properties. The solution is trivial: Don't use arrays when you [shouldn't be using them](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/).

Comment: Indexes are shown on the first picture (Firebug DOM). It's indexes with negative numbers and indexes with very big numbers.

Comment: By [definition](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array-exotic-objects), array indices are positive integers.

Comment: However, all worked fine before I tried to save variable to localstorage. Also it doesn't explain why big array indices does not save too.

Comment: It has nothing to do with localstorage, it's `JSON.stringify` does drops them.

Comment: Why do you have negative numbers at all, btw? There might be [much better alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10120535/1048572).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) does only serialise *array indices*<sup>1</sup> on `Array` objects, and discards all other properties. The solution is trivial - don't use arrays when you [shouldn't be using them](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/):

```
var MapCellData = {}; // instead of []
MapCellData[weirdProperty] = …;
```

This will be much more space-efficient in JSON as well, given how sparse your "array" is.

<sub>1: [§6.1.7, §9.4.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array-exotic-objects): An array index is a String-valued property key that is a canonical numeric String and whose numeric value i is in the range +0 ≤ i < 232−1.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, this solution is perfect. I had no idea that there is so convenient substitution of arrays.